# Creating custom user model in middle of project without erasing migration or database

Tags: python, django

In my models, I created UserManager and User and I added this in my settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.User"
```

but when I migrate it raises error related model cannot be resolved.
I searched the internet but I couldn't find the answer which solves my problem
<--->
As there is no good answer on the internet for this problem and I still didn't find a solution for it with the help of a friend here(with all this I don't know I get minus point) I think I need to ask with more details
I defined this classes in my models.py:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin
)

from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin, BaseUserManager
)


class UserManager(BaseUserManager):

    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Creates and saves a User with the given email,and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')
        try:
            with transaction.atomic():
                user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
                user.set_password(password)
                user.save(using=self._db)
                return user
        except:
            raise

    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

    def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)

        return self._create_user(email, password=password, **extra_fields)


class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    """
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=40, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    objects = UserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name', 'last_name']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(User, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        return self
```

and I added this in my settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "myapp.User"
```

I run makemigrations and it had no erroe but when I try to run migrate I give this error:

```
in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'myapp.User' cannot be resolved
```

Comment: Did you add `'myapp'` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes I did

Comment: Is it possible to post the full error (including traceback)?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem  in resolve_related_fields
    raise ValueError('Related model %r cannot be resolved' % self.remote_field.model)
ValueError: Related model 'myapp.User' cannot be resolved

Comment: The it looks like either `'myapp'` is not installed properly, or that application has no `User` model (should inherit from `Model`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I am sure my app is installed because I ran a part of project with it and it worked properly,and then in my models.py above my previous models I defined this:
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
...
like what is said here:https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-authenticate-with-jwt-in-django--cms-30460

Comment: Well then unfortunately, I think we can not help much, since there are not enough details to find the cause of this error.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I edited my question, may you please take a look and see if you can help me?

Answer (score 1):

I think this issue is that You had been using django's User model, and all of a sudden you have changed your `USER_AUTH_MODEL` to your custom `User` model. Then you are running migrations, and it is throwing error.

Actually there is no very good solution for this. Please see the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#changing-to-a-custom-user-model-mid-project) for this.

As mentioned in the documentation, for can follow the instructions in the ticket [25313](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25313) to migrate user:

1. Create a custom user model identical to auth.User, call it User (so many-to-many tables keep the same name) and set **db_table='auth_user'** (so it uses the same table)
2. Delete all your migrations(except for `__init__.py` file inside **migrations** folder)
3. Recreate a fresh set of migrations(`python manage.py makemigrations`)
4. make a backup of your database
5. Truncate the django_migrations table
6. Fake-apply the new set of migrations(`python manage.py migrate --fake`)
7. Unset **db_table**, make other changes to the custom model, generate migrations, apply them.

Answer (score 0):

follow the below instructions

> 1. create database buckup:
>    pg_dump -U user_name -d database_name --data-only > file_name.sql
> 2. go to .sql file path  and rename using run the command:
>    sed -i 's/auth_user/custom_user/g' file_name.sql
> 3. go to sql terminal run command:
>    =# select 'drop table if exists "' || tablename || '" cascade;'   from
>    pg_tables where schemaname = 'public';
>    =#\gexec
> 4. find . -path "*/migrations/*.py" -not -name "**init**.py" -delete
> 5. find . -path "*/migrations/*.pyc"  -delete
> 6. python manage.py makemigrations
> 7. python manage.py migrate
> 8. load the .sql file to data base using this command:
>    psql -U user_name -d database_name -f file_name.sql